# How to count on the two same tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I was trying using count() on two same tables to get some sort of relation
Here's my query

```
SELECT b.id, count(a) count(b.id) from 
checkins_small a, checkins_small b 
WHERE a.id =22 AND a.city = b.city AND a.date = b.date GROUP BY b.id ;
```

this is based on checkin data, I wanted to find all the people who checked in at the same city and same date as users 22 did. but this query always give me a masive number. the results for count(a.id) and count(b.id) are always the same How can I solve this?

```
SELECT a.id, count(a.id) from checkins_small a group by a.id order by count(a.id) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

this query will give this result:

```
userid  checkin times
22     ;  1783
267    ;  1607
177    ;  1508
130    ;  1477
205    ;  1456
2      ;  1368
323    ;  1151
111    ;  1092
337    ;  940
53     ;  896
```

Now, I want to find all the people who checked in at the same date and same city as user 22 did and the times those people have checked in. so the result would be like this

```
   user_id   times
```

Comment: Can you please share the tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for this sample?

Comment: Well you cannot select and group by the same column you are counting. if you want to count `b.id` then you shouldn't be selecting it, and shouldn't be grouping by it. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: if your `id` is the primary key, then your `count(a) where a.id = 22` will always be `1`. When selecting `b.id`, grouping by `b.id` - your `count(b.id)` will always be `1`

Comment: the chekins_small table contains the person who checked in, the checkin date, city.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   COUNT(b.ID) as CT,
   b.date
FROM
   checkins_small a
   INNER JOIN
   checkins_small b on b.city = a.city and b.date = a.date
WHERE
   a.ID = 22
GROUP BY
   b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.id AS user_id,
   COUNT(b.id) AS times
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT
           id,
           city,
           date
    FROM   checkins_small
    WHERE  id = 22) a,
   checkins_small b
WHERE  a.city = b.city
   AND a.date = b.date
   AND a.id <> b.id
GROUP  BY b.id;
```